# XML File Creation in Perl - Updated Requirements

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

Sorry, I am posting this again but lot of requirements have been changed and I need advice.
My First input file is

```
Root1      TBLA      KEY1      COLA      A    B    
Root1      TBLA      KEY1      COLB      D    E    
Root1      TBLA      KEY3      COLX      M    N     
Root2      TBLB      KEY4      COLX      M    N     
Root2      TBLB      KEY4      COLD      A    B   
Root3      TBLC      KEY5      COLD      A    B
```

My second input file is

```
Root1      TBLA      KEY6    
Root2      TBLB      KEY7    
Root3      TBLC      KEY8
```

My third input file is

```
Root1      TBLA      KEY9    
Root1      TBLA      KEY10    
Root3      TBLC      KEY11
```

Basically File representation is
1) First file represents the old and new values. First is root table, Second is actual table in which diff is there. Third column tells the key value. Fourth and Fifth represents old and new value.

2) Second file represents the primary key which exists in db1 only and not in db2. First is root table, Second is actual table in which key exists. Third column tells the key value

3) Third file represents the primary key which exists in db2 only and not in db1. First is root table, Second is actual table in which key exists. Third column tells the key value

The output to be created in xml format as

```
   <Data>    
    <Root1>
        <TBLA>    
            <NEW1>
                <KEY>KEY6</KEY>
            <NEW1>              
            <NEW2>
                <KEY>KEY9</KEY>
                <KEY>KEY10</KEY>
            <NEW2>              
            <MODIFIED>
                <KEY name =KEY1>
                    <COLA>
                        <oldvalue>A</oldvalue>
                        <newvalue>B</newvalue>    
                    </COLA> 
                    <COLB>    
                        <oldvalue>D</oldvalue>    
                        <newvalue>E</newvalue>     
                    </COLB>
                </KEY>
                <KEY name =KEY3>
                    <COLX>
                        <oldvalue>M</oldvalue>
                        <newvalue>N</newvalue>    
                    </COLX> 
                </KEY>
            </MODIFIED>     
        </TBLA>
    </Root1>        
    <Data>
```

THIS IS NOT COMPLETE OUTPUT. PART OF OUTPUT IS DISPLAYED
Can anyone suggest what would be the best way to do this. Should i convert this text file to hash of hashes first and then try using `pltoxml()`. does this make sense. Can `XML::Simple` or `XML::Writer` suffice this.

This is the first time I am working on xml and not sure which approach will help efficicently my solution.
A small example wrt to my req would be appreciated.

*Input file will always be sorted on Root and then TBLNAME

Output format
Output contains for every root, every table in that root and that for every table, key which exists in one and then key which exists in second only. This comes in section new1 and new2 respectively. Third section contains Modified which needs to read from first input file and list the key value and with that key value what columns are modified (their old and new value)

If I have to use XML::Simple, how do i create hashref from these files which i can pass it to XMLout. There is no key in any of these files.

Comment: Hi, Actually my original question was simple one so i got some advice on that. However i updated the question with latest comments but not sure whether it will be checked again as people have already contributed to that. So i again posted the same with new question. I am not sure if i update the question that has been answered is again looked by experts

Comment: You should not modify old questions. Creating a new one was correct. Changing the old one wasn't. I have rolled the old question back to before your edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a matter of using `split` to split the data into fields, storing it into a hash and then transforming it using [**`XML::Simple`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple).

- Note that I stick things into an array to enforce the order you intended.
- All the data is read from the `DATA` handle. You shouldn't need me to show you IO code.
- The `@processors` array is simply the different processors you would use on the various files:

Code:

```
use 5.016;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Simple qw(:strict);

my %roots;

my @processors 
    = ( sub {
           my ( $root, $table, $key, $col, $old, $new ) = split /\s+/;
           $roots{ $root }{ $table }[2]{MODIFIED}{ $col }
                = { oldvalue => $old 
                  , newvalue => $new 
                  };
           return;
        }
      , sub { 
          my ( $root, $table, $key ) = split /\s+/;
          push @{ $roots{ $root }{ $table }[0]{NEW1}{KEY} }, $key;
        }
      , sub { 
          my ( $root, $table, $key ) = split /\s+/;
          push @{ $roots{ $root }{ $table }[1]{NEW2}{KEY} }, $key;
        }
      );

my $processor = shift @processors;
while ( <> ) { 
    chomp;
    if ( $_ eq '---' ) { 
        $processor = shift @processors;
    }
    else {
        $processor->( $_ );
    }
}

my $xs = XML::Simple->new( NoAttr => 1, RootName => 'Data', );
my $xml = $xs->XMLout( \%roots, KeyAttr => {} );
say $xml;
```

It produces:

```
<Data>
  <Root1>
    <TBLA>
      <NEW1>
        <KEY>KEY6</KEY>
      </NEW1>
    </TBLA>
    <TBLA>
      <NEW2>
        <KEY>KEY9</KEY>
        <KEY>KEY10</KEY>
      </NEW2>
    </TBLA>
    <TBLA>
      <MODIFIED>
        <COLA>
          <newvalue>B</newvalue>
          <oldvalue>A</oldvalue>
        </COLA>
        <COLB>
          <newvalue>E</newvalue>
          <oldvalue>D</oldvalue>
        </COLB>
        <COLX>
          <newvalue>N</newvalue>
          <oldvalue>M</oldvalue>
        </COLX>
      </MODIFIED>
    </TBLA>
  </Root1>
  <Root2>
    <TBLB>
      <NEW1>
        <KEY>KEY7</KEY>
      </NEW1>
    </TBLB>
    <TBLB></TBLB>
    <TBLB>
      <MODIFIED>
        <COLD>
          <newvalue>B</newvalue>
          <oldvalue>A</oldvalue>
        </COLD>
        <COLX>
          <newvalue>N</newvalue>
          <oldvalue>M</oldvalue>
        </COLX>
      </MODIFIED>
    </TBLB>
  </Root2>
  <Root3>
    <TBLC>
      <NEW1>
        <KEY>KEY8</KEY>
      </NEW1>
    </TBLC>
    <TBLC>
      <NEW2>
        <KEY>KEY11</KEY>
      </NEW2>
    </TBLC>
    <TBLC>
      <MODIFIED>
        <COLD>
          <newvalue>B</newvalue>
          <oldvalue>A</oldvalue>
        </COLD>
      </MODIFIED>
    </TBLC>
  </Root3>
</Data>
```

Comment: Hi Axeman, Thanks for your help. Certain clarification is required. Can you please help. In Modified section, Key value is not displayed, so it doesn't tell these columns (old and new values) are of which keys. Also, the loop overwrites the old value as we have not used the key, i tried this `$roots{ $root }{ $table }[2]{MODIFIED}{$key}{ $col }` instead of `$roots{ $root }{ $table }[2]{MODIFIED}{ $col }`. But the display `<KEY name =KEY1>` is not coming. It is coming as `<KEY1>`(only the value is displayed)